# how to query multiple tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Start Table

**knowledge_base**

```
knowledge_id
sub_body_part_id
symptom
disease
specialization_id
gender
age
last_update
```

**main_body_part**

```
main_body_part_id
main_body_part
last_update
```

**sub_body_part**

```
sub_body_part_id
sub_body_part
last_update
```

**specialization**

```
specialization_id
specialization
last_update
```

**sub_body_part_has_main_body_part**

```
sub_body_part_id
main_body_part_id
```

End Table

This is my query. It seems correct but I don't get main_body_part table and I don't know how to query it. Sorry I'm beginner this situation. Just give me same solution and I appreciate it. :)

```
SELECT sbp.sub_body_part, s.specialization, k.symptom, k.disease, k.gender, k.age
from knowledge_base k
left join sub_body_part sbp on sbp.sub_body_part_id = k.sub_body_part_id
left join specialization s on s.specialization_id = k.specialization_id
```

This is example:

```
          Main body   | Sub body |  Disease |  symptom  |  specialization  |   gender   |   age  


           Head          Eyes        Stroke     Confusion      Neurology        Both        All
```

Comment: Well, you've managed to join three tables together... why don't you try repeating the process to join the fourth? :S

Comment: It looks like you do not have any meaningful fields to join in the 4th table...  Does the sub_body_part table have another field that references back to the main_body_part table using field main_body_part_id?  Is there another mapping table in your database that has both fields main_body_part_id and sub_body_part_id?

Comment: -1. You just asked a question similar to this a few days ago. Review the information you were given there, do some research online, and learn how to write joins.

Comment: @eggyal  Yah I try but it doesn't work :(

Comment: You don't have a main_body_part_id column at sub_body_part. Thus you cannot connect the nose with the head for example.

Comment: @DavidFleeman Sorry I forgot to mention other table. Look at the updates of my tables :)

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have added the mapping table from sub to main, try this:

```
SELECT mbp.main_body_part, sbp.sub_body_part, s.specialization, k.symptom, k.disease, k.gender, k.age
from knowledge_base k
left join sub_body_part sbp on sbp.sub_body_part_id = k.sub_body_part_id
left join sub_body_part_has_main_body_part s2m on s2m.sub_body_part_id = sbp.sub_body_part_id
left join main_body_part mbp on mbp.main_body_part_id = s2m.main_body_part_id
left join specialization s on s.specialization_id = k.specialization_id
```